# Is it possible to Upgrade from Magento 2.3.5-p1 to Magento 2.4?

Tags: upgrade, magento-upgrade, magento2.4

I am trying to upgrade from Magento 2.3.5-p1 to Magento 2.4.
I have server with PHP 7.4 and MariaDB 10.2 and when i am trying to upgrade via composer than i am facing below error

[image]

Please let us know the solution required to resolve above issue.

Thanks

Comment: "server with PHP 7.4 and MariaDB 10.2" do you have mysql installed on server?

Comment: @SanaullahAhmad, yes its already installed and error showing MySQL is not supported.

Comment: Try  to change "Store->configuration->catalog->catalog->catalog Search->Search Engine " from "MySql"  to Elastic Search and than upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: please check php7.4 version and elasticsearch installed.

First take to older version website backup and after your run direct magento 2.4.0 version.

Magento Open Source:

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.4.0 --no-update
```

Magento Commerce:

```
composer require magento/product-enterprise-edition=2.4.0 --no-update
```

And you want to read more information check this :-

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html

UPDATE:-

I will explain more in how to update latest magento version (2.4 at the moment):.

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.4.0 --no-update

composer update
```

If you are running Magento 2 commerce the command will be slightly different:

```
composer require magento/product-enterprise-edition=2.4.0 --no-update

composer update
```

Replace 2.4 with the latest M2 version.

When it is completed, run another SSH command and upgrade the Magento database:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

After that you will want to recompile if you are in production mode:

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
```

You’ve successfully performed a Magento 2 upgrade! Now go to the frontend and backend and check everything.

Answer (score 1):

You should upgrade MariaDB 10.2 to MariaDB 10.4 to use MySQL 8.x for Magento 2.4.0 version.
Please read more information at [Magento 2.4.0 release note](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/release-notes/release-notes-2-4-0-open-source.html)